# can't install pattern.nlp package in R

Tags: python, r

I am trying to Install pattern.nlp package in R but there are couple of error is coming while going through. this package is use for python Library so I have change the path for environment variable. but while running following code I am getting error.

```
$

x <- pattern_sentiment("i really really hate iphones", language = "english")



Error in data.table::setDF(score) : 
  All elements in argument 'x' to 'setDF' must be of same length
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In pyConnectionCheck() : R isn't connected to Python!

2: In pyConnectionCheck() : R isn't connected to Python!

3: In pyConnectionCheck() : R isn't connected to Python!

4: In pyConnectionCheck() : R isn't connected to Python!


$
```

Comment: I've spent the weekend fighting this problem. Did you ever get it fixed? I think I can answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Python is connected from R by using the function pyIsConnected(). If not, then use pyConnect() to make the connection.

Also ensure that pattern.nlp package is installed in Python - refer http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pattern